# I have temporary table which stores delete statement, I need to create a stored procedure during runtime which contain these delete statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

temporary table data:

```
Delete from RISKASSESSMENTRULEOVERRIDE
where RISKASSESSMENTRULEOVERRIDE.ApplicationNumber=@ApplicationNumber;  

Delete from NONPANELMORTGAGEPRODUCT
where NONPANELMORTGAGEPRODUCT.ApplicationNumber=@ApplicationNumber;
```

and so on...

I need to create a stored procedure which stores these delete statement inside that stored proc, so as when I get multiple values of  `@ApplicationNumber`, I don't need to iterate over each row, I can just have my query plan saved, as it may increase performance.

I am not sure is it possible?

Comment: Are you going for this approach because you've found iterating, or RBAR, or looping is bad? 
Just store the list of ApplicationNumbers in a table and then join on that when you delete from NONPANELMORTGAGEPRODUCT

Comment: Just wrapping inside stored proc will work

Comment: @TheGameiswar i and unable to wrap these inside stored proc,i dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to create a stored proc, why not just run delete statements with a join to your temp table?

Assuming you have a temp table called `#applications_to_delete`, with a column called `DeleteApplicationNumber`, you could just call this:

```
delete RISKASSESSMENTRULEOVERRIDE 
from 
    RISKASSESSMENTRULEOVERRIDE live
    join #applications_to_delete temp
        on (live.ApplicationNumber = temp.DeleteApplicationNumber)

delete NONPANELMORTGAGEPRODUCT 
from 
    NONPANELMORTGAGEPRODUCT live
    join #applications_to_delete temp
        on (live.ApplicationNumber = temp.DeleteApplicationNumber)
```

Comment: i want to create stored procedure which contains all the these statements from temporary tables, and while executing i will execute the stored procedure, b'coz if we want to delete for another records, the query plan will be saved and it would be faster to execute.